# How to perform Xperf callstack capture on 64b OS?

Tags: windows, performance, profiling, 64-bit, xperf

I have installed Xperf performance analyzer from Windows SDK and captured a trace as described in the documentation using following command:

```
xperf -on SysProf -stackwalk profile
```

Still, the stack trace does not contain any callstack data.

My platform is Vista 64b. Are there any special settings or tricks needed to capture callstacks on 64b Windows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some more searching I have found one setting:

Set registry value DisablePagingExecutive = 1 and reboot (see [Windows Performance Toolkit FAQ](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wptk_v4/thread/282e5beb-0afd-411b-9a81-a0bbbf569dfe/)).

While this sounds great, it does not seem to help at my system, still no call-stacks.

---

After contacting Microsoft support their reply was with x64 Vista you can capture only callstacks of x64 native applications, not 32b ones.

---

Windows 7 seems to have removed the limitation and it works fine on Win 7 x64, at least this says [Valve presentation on Xperf](http://www.valvesoftware.com/publications/2011/ValveXperf-Dawson.pdf).